# Filling sequential IDs starting at the current highest ID +1

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am creating an upload document that I will use to push new accounts into our billing system. I have a table that displays all current accounts and their IDs (VEX_CustomL0). I want to fill the ID column in the upload document starting at the current highest ID + 1.

I tried creating a temporary table (NumberLine) that contains sequential numbers that generates the next 500 IDs. Then I updated the upload file with the IDs.

```
UPDATE UPLOAD_FILE, NumberLine 
SET UPLOAD_FILE.C_EZCOM = NumberLine.VAL;
```

I wanted Access to take the top values (1-12) in the NumberLine and populate the upload document. Instead it took the lowest values (488 - 500).

Comment: Try sorting your NumberLine query the other way. Descending starts at the highest and goes down. We would have to see how you are building the NumberLine query to help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description and the limited information provided, I would assume that your table `NumberLine` simply contains a 500 records with the `VAL` field containing a sequential integer, e.g.:

```
+-----+
| VAL |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   2 |
|   3 |
| ... |
| 500 |
+-----+
```

With this assumption, note that your current `UPDATE` query is updating records using a cartesian product: that is, for each record in `UPLOAD_FILE`, update the value of `C_EZCOM` with the value of `VAL` for ***every***  record in `NumberLine`...

You can observe this behaviour directly by changing your `UPDATE` query to a `SELECT` query, outputting the `C_EZCOM` and `VAL` fields.

Consequently, the resulting value held by each `C_EZCOM` record will simply be whichever record in `NumberLine` was last encountered by the `UPDATE` query (which, unless the data has a defined sort order using an `ORDER BY` clause, could potentially be any record).

Whilst I can identify issues with your current solution, it is difficult to advise of the best method of achieving your goal unless you were to provide some sample data along with the expected result.